# Expo React Native Rendering Issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, expo, rendering

I have a component which shows default picture when no picture is selected and shows the picture when selected. I pass the image as prop to it. Below is my component code:

```
  renderDefault() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.emptyImageContainer}>
        <Image
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.hexagonImage}
          source={require('../resources/hexagon.png')}
        />
        <Image
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.cameraImage}
          source={require('../resources/camera.png')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderImage() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          resizeMode="contain"
          style={styles.chosenImage}
          source={{ uri: this.props.uri }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const displayImage = this.props.uri
      ? this.renderImage()
      : this.renderDefault();
    return <View style={styles.emptyImageContainer}>{displayImage}</View>;
  }
}
export default PhotoComponent;
```

In the main file when the picture is selected it gets passed to it as
`<PhotoComponent uri={this.state.uploadSourceTop} />` 
This runs as expected on IOS however on android it doesn't show the picture unless I refresh the `PhotoComponent`
It used to work on android and I can't find why its behaving this way.
I have checked and the uri gets passed to it.

Comment: Did you restart your app? sometimes the previous states/variables are stored in the cache and not updated to defaults when rerendering

Comment: @Ahmadhassan I did that. It actually loads up correct. However doesn't show the right picture after its updated.

Comment: check `styles` by setting a height and width to the images.

Comment: @Ahmadhassan   I added a <Text> component above the image and now the image is shown when rendered!  `<Text style={{ height: 0 }}></Text>`